# how to save a file through git

Tags: git

I am having trouble saving the java program I am working on through git. I have been saving the java program, then going to git and using git add . the problem is that when I go to use the git commit -m command, gir tells me there is nothing to commit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the output of `git status`? Do you see any file staged for commit?

Comment: $ git status                                                        # on branch master                                                  #                                                                   # initial commit                                                    #                                                                   nothing to commmit

Answer (score 0):

If you have no files, then `git add .` won't add anything (because there is nothing to add). If you have not added anything, then `git commit` will tell you there is nothing to commit.

It sounds like the solution to your problem would be to create a file first, then `git add .` and `git commit`.

Comment: I did make a file. its a java program. is there another step for allowing the file to be used in git?

Comment: No, Git adds all files found in the directory. (You did save the java file to the correct directory, right?)

Answer (score 0):

When using git, 'git status' is your friend and the best way to work out what's actually going on.
If git status is telling you there is nothing to commit, then there really is nothing to commit.
'Nothing to commit' basically means all file changes are currently saved in git.

git commit -m "This is the best codez"  # does a commit of uncommitted files and includes whatever commit message you set.

Try this next.

```
Make a file in the directory, eg test.txt
$ git status # have a look what's going on
$ git add test.txt
$ git status
$ git commit -m "test completed"
$ git status
```